# setOnItemClickListener not working if the list item has a link

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I have a list view and this list view contains list items(Custom layout) with links if i click on link then text view is not clickable, i want both textview and link to be clickable i have added all stuff like

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
 android:focusable="false"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textSize="28sp" />
```

and this my xml file
nothing is working 
thanks in advance

Comment: updated my question and added the xml

Comment: it helps if you use recyclerview instead which does not steal your focus :o

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote some example for you.

---

**`MainActivity2Activity.java`**:

```
public class MainActivity2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spanned[] data = new Spanned[]{
            Html.fromHtml("Some text and link: www.google.com Google"),
            Html.fromHtml("Some text and link: www.google.com Google"),
            Html.fromHtml("Some text and link: www.google.com Google")};

    ListView mListView;
    ArrayAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, data);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Item at position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Spanned>{

        private Context mContext;
        private Spanned[] mData;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, Spanned[] data) {
            super(context, -1, data);
            mContext = context;
            mData = data;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.link_listview_item, parent, false);

            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item)).setText(mData[position]);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item)).setTag(position);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "TextView click at position: " + (Integer) view.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

**`activity_main_activity2.xml`**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.dinamicgridview.app.MainActivity2Activity">

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**`link_listview_item.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:http="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="Some text"/>

    <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:id="@+id/space"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### **Demo**

Click on text:
[image]
Click on link:
[image]
Click on item:
[image]

Comment: thanks @Alexander links are clickable but i need text to be clickable  along with the links that in listview

Comment: @Alexander Get PositionData on String and then Go to new Activity or Go to url

Comment: @amitsharma, whats wrong with my answer? As you can see all works fine. Describe your problem more detail please

Comment: Alexander sorry man i was write for @Ghouse Pasha it was just happening wrong no issue in your answer..

Comment: @Alexander there is no need lot of code and snaps at stack are you free for work or Like describe in details ...

Comment: @Alexander Your answer is correct you should not west his time to answers for questions as i have seen you have write or add full details answer

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code it may help you this is small code to do it

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int pos, long
   mylng) {

    String selectedFromList =(lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
  URL url;
  Uri uri;
 try {
     url = new URL(selectedFromList );
      uri = Uri.parse( url.toURI().toString() );
      } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
   } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}  
}                 
});
```